# What happens when I change the COM port number in device manager?

Tags: winapi

I'm looking for a way to change the number of the COM port, but without the need of user interfaction. In my case I have an USB/Serial adapter, and it appears as COM3 - but I want it to become COM1.

Others assert that the number is assigned by the driver and cannot be changed, ans so on... But I already found lots of threads telling me that I have to do some hacks in the Registry (HKLM\SYSTEM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM and HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum{Name of service}).

OK, so far - so good. Changing the settings in the registry let me access device as \.\COM1, but it still shows up as "COM3" in device manager. I figured out where this string is saved, but only SYSTEM has access to that.

So I am asking myself: What I need to do that may freshly renamed COM Port appears as COM1 in device manager as expected?

Does anybody knows?

Comment: you not need change com number at all. for what ?

Comment: Editing the SERIALCOMM merely makes a program fail that tries to open the serial port.  It is the USB device driver that creates the virtual serial port, it writes SERIALCOMM but doesn't read it.  Some USB devices allow you to state a preference for the COM port number in a property page but that is very uncommon today.  Programs that use a serial port always require a configuration option to select the desired port.

Comment: @RbMm: The answer is: I have a device with serial port, and the connector is labeled as COM1. I could set it to COM1 in past and it remained as COM1 in past, but due to hardware changes it becomes COM3 when I deploy the Windows image to a new device. Do you agree that it may be confusing for users when they see COM1 at the connector and COM3 in the device manager?

Comment: @WillyK. - you need not hardcode device name or symbolic link, but get it in runtime. say via `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT..`

Comment: I think I did not explained clear enough what is going on: COM1 is usually unused, but when I install my image to a new device, the USB serial ports are always starting at COM3. I just want to change this since the connector is labeled as COM1 - so that users can address it as COM1 as it manners.

Answer (score 0):

SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty() did the trick for me. It may be not the best solution at all, but it works.